# Angular Material Design - error of import elements

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MdRadioGroup' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation
```

In file `app.module` I have:

```
import {
  MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE,
  MdRadioGroup,
  MdButtonModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

And below in section `@NgModule`:

```
 imports: [
   MdRadioGroup
 ]
```

But it does not work

Comment: angular-material2 I take it?

Comment: Yes, I import from `from '@angular/material';`

Comment: In package.json: `"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import in the module:

```
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and then in the @NgModules:

```
imports: [
...
  MdRadioModule,
...
]
```